# How reference data in returned promise

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

How do I access the data array in the Promise.Object.collection?[image]

Comment: do ```fetchRequests().then(fetchResult =>{ // Your operation })```

Comment: Please do not put code in an image.  It can be searched.  It can't be copied into a test program to run it ourselves.  It can't be copied into answers to show you how to fix it.  It can be accessed on a mobile device very efficiently.  Paste your code as plain text and format it appropriately here.

Comment: If you wanted get user list, the appropriate http method is `GET` instead `POST`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have everything. All you need to do is to set the return on each if and itacate over a map, each item of the map is an object of collection

```js
function fetchRequests (){
....
}).then(responde => response.json())
.then(responde => {
    const { result, collection } = response;
   If (result===“success”) {
      return collection.map(item => new Person(item))
   }
})
```

You need to create a new class of the object your getting on the collection

```js
class Perdon {

    constructor (data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
   }
}
```

Where ever you call your method fetchRequests

```js
async function funcCaller () {
   const people = await fetchRequests();
   // people have your collection 
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I can access the data from within the fetch, but I can't access it outside the fetch.  I need the data returned to an outside var as I need to use it to act upon other code.

Comment: Ohh I see let me change the example